# Entropy of a deterministic reversible system

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, time-reversal-symmetry, determinism

Suppose a deterministic reversible system evolving from state *A* of gas located in a small bottle in an otherwise empty room, to state *B* where the gas is dispersed throughout the room.

Why is the entropy of state *B* said to be higher than the entropy of state *A* if all you need to fully describe state *B*, is to describe state *A* together with a single time scalar *t*?

Comment: Who are these people that say than entropy increases in a reversible process??? Textbooks say entropy stays constant in a reversible process.

Comment: @stuffu That is incorrect. Variation of entropy is the sum of two terms: exchanged entropy (with environment) and created entropy. Only the latter is zero during a reversible process. If there's heat exchanged during the process, entropy can still vary.

Comment: Define what you mean by a “deterministic reversible system “. The term reversible normally refers to a process or cycle, not a system

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the actual equations of state that describe this gas to actually calculate the entropy change.

If we assume it's an *ideal* gas, entropy depends only on internal energy and volume. Since internal energy won't change as the gas interacts with nothing, and volume increases, entropy increases.

If it's not an ideal gas, maybe it's possible it's a special gas that decreases it's temperature as it expands, in such way that the entropy actually remains constant as it expands. It's *possible*. But it would need to have very very specific equations of state to manage that.

So we can't actually say that the entropy increases unless you give the equations of state of your gas.

As for your mention of describing B as A plus a time scalar, that's not how entropy is calculated. Entropy depends on the state, and A and B are different states. That B is A later in time does not change this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "deterministic reversible system" (you didn’t answer my question) since reversible normally refers to a process or cycle, not a system. I'm also not sure what you mean by state B being state A with a "single time scalar". In any case, the process you describe, the spontaneous expansion of a gas into a vacuum, is clearly irreversible (you would not expect the gas to spontaneously return to the bottle).

From a statistical mechanics perspective, the increase in entropy is due to the fact that the larger the volume for the given gas, the more ways there are to distribute the molecules in that volume (the more micro states).

From a macro thermodynamics perspective (i.e., the relationships between large scale bulk properties of a system) we can calculate the entropy change by assuming any convenient reversible process that connects the initial and final equilibrium states in conformance with the first law, and apply the following definition for entropy change which is for a reversible transfer of heat:

$$\Delta S=\int \frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$

If we assume the room has rigid thermally insulated walls (an isolated system), and the gas is an ideal gas, the change in internal energy will be zero. And since internal energy for an ideal gas depends only on temperature, we can assume a reversible isothermal process connects the states. For such a process the change in entropy is then given by

$$\Delta S=nR\ln\frac{V_{f}}{V_i}$$

Where $V_i$ is the volume of the bottle, and $V_f$ is the volume of the bottle plus the room.

Hope this helps.